# Overflow or Underflow Exception Querying Cosmos DocumentDB

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm encountering an unexpected error trying to query a Cosmos DocumentDB.  I have run my query in Azure Data Explorer and I am getting the expected results, however, when I attempt to run it using the C# SQL API, I am getting various errors (after different attempts) including "Overflow or Underflow in Arithmetic Operation", or "NullReferenceException".  When I use ReadDocumentAsync, I get a document without error, so I know my cosmos client and collection uri are OK.

Could someone please help me understand why I may be having a problem with this.

Here is how I am building and executing my query:

```
        using (var cosmosClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosEndPointUrl), cosmosAuthKey))
        {
            var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            var sql = @"SELECT TOP 10 p.Id As QuoteKey
                ,pol.Proposer.Forename
                ,pol.Proposer.Surname
                ,pol.Proposer.ResidentialAddress.Postcode
                ,veh.Vrn
                FROM Proposal p
                    JOIN pol IN p.QuoteRequest.Policies
                    JOIN veh IN pol.Vehicles
                WHERE(pol.Proposer.Forename = @Forename OR @Forename = '')
                      AND(pol.Proposer.Surname = @Surname OR @Surname = '')
                      AND(pol.Proposer.ResidentialAddress.Postcode = @Postcode OR @Postcode = '')
                      AND(veh.Vrn = @Vrn OR @Vrn = '')";
            var ps = new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter[]
                                                    {
                                                        new SqlParameter { Name = "@Forename", Value = criteria.Firstname }, 
                                                        new SqlParameter { Name = "@Surname", Value = criteria.Surname }, 
                                                        new SqlParameter { Name = "@Postcode", Value = criteria.Postcode }, 
                                                        new SqlParameter { Name = "@Vrn", Value = criteria.RegNo }, 
                                                    });
            var sqlQuerySpec = new SqlQuerySpec(sql, ps);
            var fo = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 };
            List<QuoteSummary> results = new List<QuoteSummary>();
            var query = cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, sqlQuerySpec, fo).AsDocumentQuery();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var demiResults = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<QuoteSummary>();
                results.AddRange(demiResults);
            }

            return results.ToList();
        }
```

Here are the other couple of classes used:

```
public class QuoteSummary
{
    public string QuoteKey { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Vrn { get; set; }
}
public class QuoteSearchCriteria
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
}
```

Please help.  This issue is eating into my time at a Hack I'm attending at Microsoft and no one I've asked so far knows why it isn't working.

Comment: is there any chanse that one of that long chucks of properties is null? e.g. in  `pol.Proposer.ResidentialAddress.Postcode` `ResidentialAddress` is null

Comment: did you execute exactly the same query in Azure Data Explorer? Do you have some custom indexes?

Comment: I checked the indexing settings, and only the defaults are being used, which automatically index all number and string fields.  The data generator tool we built creates fully populated Proposals that contain Proposer, Vehicles and ResidentialAddress, so none of the nested properties should be null.  I'm now looking to see if I can find out whether the indexes are being used, or whether some sort of trace can be enabled.

Comment: and when u receive NullReferenceException - you probably can track what var is null from exception, right?

Answer (score 0):

When I got this exception, it was environment+dependencies related:
My configuration was Azure App service, which queries azure cosmosdb.
What I was missing is the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) in the Web API level. It obviously existed as a dependency in other class library which was referenced, but wasn't referenced directly at the top level running application (Web API in my case).